# PS1 correct line wrapping in Bash

Tags: bash, ps1

I want to execute a command that writes some dynamic info to my shell prompt. It works fine if I do the coloring statically, because I can just put `\[` and `\]` before and after the escape sentence:

```
 '\[\e[0;91m\]$(printSomething)\[\e[0m\]'
```

But if the coloring is dynamic, and I want the external script to print it, then it doesn't work. Now I can't write the escape sequences into the PS1 directly. But if the external script prints `\[` and `\]`, then the shell displays it literally.

Is there any way to make it work?

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamic coloring scheme" and "the external script to print it"?

Comment: The external script which prints the command prompt data also prints the coloring escape sequences, because it depends on the data.

Comment: How does the script print the command prompt? `echo`? `readline`? Are you executing an interactive shell?

Comment: The script uses `echo` to print the prompt. It prints both the escape sequences needed for coloring and the text to be printed.

Comment: Now, I'm confused. What exactly isn't working? Can you please edit your question with a minimal example of the two scripts, the output you get and what you expect instead.

Comment: It doesn't matter now, I got my answer. With the `PROMPT_COMMAND` variable I can do just what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `PROMPT_COMMAND` to reset `PS1` each time you display it. To take your original prompt:

```
prompt_cmd () {
    PS1='\[\e[0;91m\]'
    PS1+=$(printSomething)
    PS1+='\[\e[0m\]'
}

PROMPT_COMMAND=prompt_cmd
```

I assume you want some different color. To do that, you could have some environment variable that `prompt_cmd` reads:

```
prompt_cmd () {
    PS1="\[\e[0;${PROMPT_COLOR}m\]" # note the double quotes
    PS1+=$(printSomething)
    PS1+='\[\e[0m\]'
}
```

or you can run some code in `prompt_cmd` itself that determines which color to use.